# Doubt with retrieving values

Tags: php

I have created a page with name `edit.php`. I have moved on this page from `action.php` using a edit button. I have successfully retrieved the values in the respective text boxes and other form items. I have problem that if by mistake this `edit.php` page is refreshed all values are gone. What is other way to maintain the values? Though thing are going well if page is not refreshed. If session variable is created than how values are retrieved of both that is of session variable and from database?

What I have did with problem.. I have requested "albumid" on `action.php` page..

```
session_start();
$aid = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['albumid']);
```

Now if `action.php` page is requested through `edit.php` page using edit button. than I have created a session variable. and destroyed it after successful update query.

```
if (isset($_POST["edit"])) {
$_SESSION["aid"]=$aid;
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE a_id =".$_SESSION["aid"]) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result); }
```

It means now session is created.. if page is refreshed than also session values remains and accordingly values are selected from this variable.

```
if($_POST['update']!="") {
Update query
session destroyed }
```

Than also my problem is not solved that is if page is refreshed before hitting update button I am loosing all values.

Answer (score 0):

session variables are just data you put into the `$_SESSION` superglobal. Accessing them is no different than accessing any other array, except that the session array is saved for you automatically. All you need to remember is to do a [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) before doing anything with the session.

```
$_SESSION['formfield1'] = $_POST['formfield1'];
$_SESSION['formfield2'] = $_POST['formfield2'];
etc...


<input type="text" name="formfield1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['formfield1']) ?>" />
```

By default, PHP uses file-based sessions. To put it into a database, you'd have to write your own session handlers and point PHP to them using [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler).

Answer (score 0):

When you submit, save the values in appropriately named $_SESSION members.  Then on your page, if you can't find the members in $_GET/$_POST, you can choose to look them up in $_SESSION.  Or vice versa.  Every time the user submits a form though, you should always update $_SESSION so that the values are the most current.  (in case they backtrack, or resubmit, or whatnot).

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
}
elseif (empty($_POST) && !empty($_SESSION['post'])) {
    $_POST = $_SESSION['post'];
}
```

just don't forget to `unset($_SESSION['post']);` when you're done with it.

Comment: it's better to use !isset than !empty in this case i think

Comment: `!isset` and `!empty` are opposite concepts ;)  -- but to your point, it shouldn't matter.  `empty()` won't produce a warning if the key doesn't exist, and will prevent assignment if `$_SESSION['post'] == array()`; however, `isset()` will allow it to assign an empty array, and the same net effect is achieved.

Comment: i'm sorry, i tried to mean using **isset** instead of **!empty**

Comment: What to do in condition I am retrieving values from database..like `<?= $row['a_name']?>`. This would only be successful if button is clicked for update. and than also values are already saved and I have mentioned that. than whats need of creating session variables..?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, I think you need some variables from database as well as from the session.

Simply put the key of your database tuple (or keys in case of multiple values) along with other stuff. Page, upon loading will check for the session variables and when it finds the key, it can use it to retrieve the data from the database.

In your previous page, the code will look like this :

```
    $_SESSION["player_key"] = 56;
    $_SESSION["tournament_key"] = 100;
```

And current page, start processing like this :

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        $player = $_SESSION["player_key"];
        $tournament = $_SESSION["tournament_key"];

        /*
         * your database connection steps
         */
        $query = "select * from player where pid=".$player;
        $res = mysql_query($query);
        /*
        Now assign values for your forms/components here or anywhere in the page. You don't have        to read anything from the querystring.
        */
    ?>
```